# Any liability for receiving mail for elder parents

Tags: liability

My in-laws were put into a nursing home.

If we have their mail sent to our address can we be any liable for any of their bills?

I assume the answer is no, because we are not signing for any of their bills, but wanted to double check.

We want to have their mail sent to us so we can manage their bills for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot be liable for their bills.

However, you could be liable to your in-laws if you fail to manage their bills properly. For example, if you are acting as their agents and incurred late fees or other penalty charges due to your negligence then they would be liable to the biller and you would be liable to them.

You also need their permission to open their mail. Opening another persons mail without permission is a crime.